# Do not add object to object list if already exists

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am doing a fairly simple query for contact records using dynamic soql using the following method:

```
public PageReference contactSearch() {
    contactResultSetSize = 0;
    if(!String.isEmpty(firstname) || !String.isEmpty(lastname) || !String.isEmpty(company)) {
        string soql = 'Select firstname, lastname, account.Name, account.BillingStreet, account.BillingCity, account.BillingState, account.BillingPostalCode From Contact';
        String whereClause = ''; 

        if(!String.isEmpty(firstname)) {
            whereClause = ' Where firstname like \'%' + firstname + '%\'';
        }
        if(!String.isEmpty(lastname)) {
            if(!String.isEmpty(firstname)) {
                whereClause += ' AND lastname like \'%' + lastname + '%\'';
            }
            else {
                whereClause = ' Where lastname like \'%' + lastname + '%\'';
            }
        }
        if(!String.isEmpty(company)) {
            if(!String.isEmpty(firstname) || !String.isEmpty(lastname)) {
                whereClause += ' AND account.Name like \'%' + company + '%\'';
            }
            else {
                whereClause = ' Where account.Name like \'%' + company + '%\'';
            }
        }
        soql = soql + whereClause;

        List<Contact> searchResults = Database.query(soql);
        contactResultSetSize = searchResults.size();
        if(contactLinesForPage == null) {
            contactLinesForPage = new List<ContactWrapper>();
        }

        for(Contact c : searchResults) {
            contactLinesForPage.add(new ContactWrapper(contactLinesForPage.size(), c, ''));
        }
    }
    return null;    
}
```

I am using a wrapper class and contactLinesForPage is a list of my wrapper object:

```
public List<ContactWrapper> contactLinesForPage {get; set;}
```

As a user does multiple searches, I don't want to re-add records to the searchResults list.  How can I check if a record already exists in my object so I don't have duplicate records returned in the search?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a check if  contactLinesForPage allready contains this contact. Something like this:

```
  for(Contact c : searchResults) {
        Boolean toInsert = true;
        for(ContactWrapper cw : contactLinesForPage){
             if(cw.contact.Id == c.Id){
                 toInsert=false;
             }
        }
        if(toInsert){
           contactLinesForPage.add(new ContactWrapper(contactLinesForPage.size(), c, ''));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use a map.  Add the ContactWrapper objects to the map.  The key to the map is an id.  If they add a duplicate contact it will simply overwrite the one already there.  Your code would simply be

```
aMap.put(cw.id, cw);  // one line eliminates duplicates.
```

When you want the list of ContactWrappers, simply return `aMap.values();`

If you want to abstract the behavior of maintaining the collection of Contacts, create a ContactCollection class and hide the implementation in there.  This would provide something more reusable as well as a good pattern for similar situations.